# Instagram endpoint to retrieve @mentions

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, social-media

Fair enough, `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/<userid>/media/recent/?access_token=XXXX` gives me the recent media entries user's history. And  `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/<tag_name>/media/recent?access_token=XXXX` gives me the list of media where the #hashtag has been used.

I am surprised that I couldn't figure out the endpoint to get all media where @user has been mentioned just like #hashtag

Any specific anectodte or url sample might help.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing on the official API that I know of that will give you mentions. There is this little trick that you can do via your web browser though: https://instagram.com/api/v1/news/inbox/ to see the logged-in user's notifications (including @mentions). If you just want to process it for personal use you might be able to run some javascript with a GET to that URL; but I don't think you'll be able to build it into an application. Notifications are inherently private so I'm not surprised that they left that out of the public API.